# Solr proximity search return no result

Tags: solr

The query I'm using is `q=name:"william test bay"~2`.

Schema.xml has the following:

```
  <field name="name" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

The follow two is the response I want to return but in fact no result is returned:

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "william bay",
        "_version_": 1561163645757423600
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "william bay photography",
        "_version_": 1561163645757423600
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'd like to know why. For example, I want to match "william test bay" to "william bay". I thought the edit distance is 1, just delete term "test"? In fact even `name:"william test bay"~1000` doesn't work.

Currently using Solr 4.10.3. This is the one used by Cloudera Search so I couldn't upgrade it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Proximity Searches

In Proximity all the phrase query keyword has to be present in document. In your case **test** keyword is not present. That's why you are not getting any result.

A proximity search looks for terms that are within a specific distance from one another.
The **distance** referred to here is the **number of term movements needed to match the specified phrase**.But not to delete the keyword from the phrase query.
[Example]

```
text : william bay photography
query : william photography
```

To match above query distance has to be one. Because only one word has to be moved for search string to matched with the text.

```
q:"william photography"~1
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Then how can I use query "william bay photography" to get text "william photography"? Is there a way aside from proximity search to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Query: `q=name:(william test bay)`